# Is There an .xml Format File that Excel Can Read

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, spreadsheet, xml, generator

I'd like to use C++ to generate an Excel file.

I know that Excel can read .csv files, but I was looking for something with more power. For example, the ability to create separate sheets and insert equations into cells.

Is there a format available to me for this?

Comment: Check this one out : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, Excel can read XML files, see: [Overview of XML in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80#bmxml_data_and_schema_files):

> Overview of how Excel works with XML data
>
> 1. Adding an XML schema file (.xsd) to a workbook.
> 2. Mapping XML schema elements to individual cells or XML tables
> 3. Importing an XML data file (.xml) and binding the XML elements to mapped cells.
> 4. Entering data, moving mapped cells, and leveraging Excel functionality, while preserving XML structure and definitions.
> 5. Exporting revised data from mapped cells to an XML data file.

---

You can for example use the [LibXl](http://www.libxl.com/) library to read and write Excel (xml) files, or the [SimpleXlsxWriter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/) library.